# How to filter elements in a dynamic element

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to show a "live" table of contents in a separate div, based on a source textarea. This involves hiding everything but h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 tags. How would I do this? I tried several functions using .show() and .hide() on #toc elements, but it had no effect.

Can you point me in the right direction?

Here's the jQuery I wrote, with my question in comments. This 'working' version is at http://jsfiddle.net/supertrue/vQvQE/

```
    // selector for the source textarea
    var textarea = $('textarea#source');
    // selector for the destination
    var destination = $('#toc');

    textarea.keyup(function() {

        destination.html( textarea.val() );

    });

    // now hide everything in #toc except h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6
    // How do I do this?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Josh's CSS trick is pretty cool and I'd probably go with that. But, if you want to use jQuery (perhaps you want to mangle the HTML a little more on its way to `#toc`) then you're better off looking for what you want rather than trying to get rid of what you don't want:

```
source.keyup(function() {
    var html = '<div>' + source.val() + '</div>';
    var hs   = $(html).find('h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6');
    destination.empty().append(hs);
});
```

The `<div>` wrapper allow us to use [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) so that we don't have to worry about [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) and how deep in the DOM the headers are.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/EbkTZ/

Comment: I like your solution because it sort of protects from x-site scripting.  What I don't understand is, why does it do that? If you add a script tag to alert a message, the unfiltered version will always execute the script, but your method does not.

Comment: @rkw: AFAIK the `<div>` wrapper sorts out the `<script>` elements. The browser pushes `<script>` outside the `<div>` and then it gets ignored because `find` looks *inside* things. Try `$('<div><script>x</script></div>')` in the console and you'll see that it gets turned into `[<div>,<script>]`. So the protection is probably browser-dependent.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit your CSS like so:

```
/** edit this **/
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 { font-weight: bold; color: #069; display: block !important;}

/** add this **/
div#toc *
{
  display:none;   
}
```

This will hide all children inside of the div with the id of `toc`, but the `!important;` `display` directive on the `h`s will ignore that.

Comment: That's pretty clever, nice job.

Comment: @muistooshort: Thanks! :) I'm a programmer by trade, but have too lately been picking up CSS slack at work... :P

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
destination.find(':not(h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6)')
```

See work example here: http://jsfiddle.net/mikhailov/AdsbA/1/